# Aggregation multiplicity UML

Tags: uml, aggregation, multiplicity

In aggregation, does the **diamond shape side** have a multiplicity of 1 maximum, or can it be 0..* ? Or is it depending of a point of view ?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you need to be specific about which 'diamond' you mean as a empty diamond in *aggregation* and a filled diamond is *composition*?

If you mean empty diamond then Icepack is correct, and you are confusing 2 separate things.  *Multiplicity* is not related to *Aggregation* so a 'diamond shaped' *aggregation* indicator can have any *multiplicity* you like as they are unrelated.

If you mean filled diamond ie *composition* then the example someone has posted won't really help you as it's saying: "There are many departments but `only 1` University (*multiplicity*)" and that "if all departments are deleted then University is also deleted (*composition*)".

I am struggling to think of a good example where *composition* end wouldn't be `1 only` and as far as I can think it would never be `0..*` as you can have a class which has to delete something which may not ever exist?  I could however be `1..*` ie *many to many*, for example Exam and Exam Questions.

The multiplicity may be `1..*` to `1..*`  ie exam have `1 or more` question and a question can reside in `1 or more` exams.  Filled diamond (*composition*) at Exam end would mean that if all questions were deleted then all exams would be deleted too

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be 0..*. There is a good example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation): Department has several professors and each professor may belong to several departments at the same time.

Comment: @sfinnie you're welcome to use any means you like to represent this kind of relation. I don't know any better way

Comment: it's a straight binary.  The hollow diamond tells you nothing that a straight binary wouldn't.  It's just visual noise.

Comment: But don't take my word for it: read this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640885/uml-aggregation-vs-association/9643017#9643017) to see what Jim Rumbaugh, UML co-author, has to say about it.

Comment: don't see any contradiction. aggregation adds details. it's up to you to decide whether you need these details or not. besides, aggregation isn't the issue here but multiplicity of a specific side in the relation. the answer is the same for simple association

Comment: Didn't say there was contradiction. I said there was confusion.  The fact the original question was asked attests to that.  My point was (is) that UML aggregation, as currently defined, is rarely a useful concept.  As for adding "details", depends what you mean by "detail".  The only well-defined semantic it adds is recursive acyclicity.  Otherwise it doesn't say _anything_ a straight binary doesn't.  And very few people know the acyclic property.  So you have to point it out explicitly anyway.  [ctd]

Comment: Of course, you may have your own conventions for using aggregation: so when you see an aggregation instead of a binary you think "Ah, ok, this has special property xx".  And that's fine, the language is there to be used.  I've found it just causes confusion - so don't use it. YMMV.  I suspect we're getting well off topic for the OP now though...

Comment: @sfinnie I see aggregation and composition as further specializations of association. At a later stage of design each association becomes either association or composition. I mainly use aggregation relation to manifest that it's not composition (and composition in the similar manner). If it's not important for the specific diagram, I omit it. But indeed, it's way off topic...