# Is there association relation between class P and class A?

Tags: c++, oop

```
class P
{
public:
    int x,y,z;
    P(int x,int y,int z)
    {
        this->x=x;
        this->y=y;
        this->z=z;
    }
};
class A
{
public:
    vector<P>p;
   // p.push_back(P(1,2,3));
};
```

Is there any association relation between class P and class A since vector is of class type?

Comment: its composition not association

Comment: See dupes: [What is the difference between association, aggregation and composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/what-is-the-difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition) and also this: [C++ : Association, Aggregation and Composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779394/c-association-aggregation-and-composition)

Comment: What's written in comments cannot be put there. If you plan to remove the comments prefix `//`, you better have to remove the whole comment. Instructions need to be written inside a function.