# How work with nested composite objects?

Tags: c#, java

I have the following classes in my application:

- `User`
- `Log`
- `LogRecord`

Each user have a list of logs, and each log consists of multiple log records. Now, since log records should be removed when the log it belongs to is removed each log is a composite. When a user is deleted the logs that the user have should also be deleted. So it is also a composite.

Does this mean that the user needs to have a method that adds a `LogRecord` object? Or am I allowed to get a `Log` object from the user and then add/remove etc log records from that and then  pass the log back to the user?

I mean, does this mean that I am not "allowed" to talk about Log and LogRecords outside of the user context? I am so confused about the definition of composition and how it should be done.

Comment: When you say "composite" are you thinking about e.g. the UML relationship "Composition"?

Comment: From a programming point of view I would follow OOD principles and keep things local, so let the Log class manage the LogRecords exclusively. Since there are more than one logs how do you want to pick a specific one? It may be cleaner (but also more work) to introduce a LogManager which encapsulates log management (since one day you may want to merge or split logs). What you do should depend on your goal of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean, does this mean that I am not "allowed" to talk about Log and
>   LogRecords outside of the user context?

If you want to model a real composition, you would not be able to access the Log and LogRecords after you have instantiated a User object (see [Implementation difference between Aggregation and Composition in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881552/implementation-difference-between-aggregation-and-composition-in-java)).

However, I think you would want to model something different here. You would want to create LogRecord objects and potentially Log objects after a User object is instantiated. You would have to model this as an aggregate then.

Comment: Ah, so composition is only the correct term when they are created at the same time as the parent? Otherwise I am not sure if I understand because you could have a method on the user that accept parameters for logs etc...but this is very impractical though and it was the reason that I asked.

Comment: Yes, I would understand it like that. Without the parent, the parts cannot exist, so they must be created at the same time. But there is no black and white programming...there rarely is a use case where you use composite or aggregation exclusively in my experience.