# Code difference between Aggregation and Composition

Tags: java, design-patterns, aggregation, composition

Can anyone give code example to show the difference between Aggregation and Composition. I have already [Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644273/what-is-the-difference-between-aggregation-composition-and-dependency#) and did not understood how they differ in code.

Please show the difference through code.

Comment: Youve got here a nice example in this page.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881552/implementation-difference-between-aggregation-and-composition-in-java

Comment: understood that ... thnks fr the link

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between a composition and an aggregation is that a composition is a **1-on-1** relation and aggregation a **1-to-many**.
To be clear: a class has only one professor and therefore it is a composition relation and a class can have multiple students so it is an aggregation.

To translate this to actual code a Class-object (class in the sense of a class in school) could have a list of students and only a single Professor field. This would indicate that the class has a **1-to-many** relationship with students but a **1-on-1** relationship with a professor.

For example in code:

```
public class SchoolClass
{
    Professor mProfessor;
    List<Student> mStudents;
}
```