# Implementing Composition in Java

Tags: java, uml, relationship, composition

```
class Book {
    private Chapter[] chapters = new Chapter[5];
 }

class Chapter {
    private Book book;
}
```

[image: Relationship]

Is this the correct way to implement the above relationship?
I need explanation on this. Thanks.

Comment: a Book has Chapters, the way you wrote it, is that the Chapter also has a Book. remove that line

Comment: A book can have Chapters... chapters having a book is weird... so remove the cyclic reference to a book in the Chapter class...

Comment: remove the Book book object inside Chapter class..and it is okay now...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881552/implementation-difference-between-aggregation-and-composition-in-java

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here: composition means that the chapters are always part of one book and when you delete the book you delete the chapters as well. Your code right now could be a composition or it could be an aggregation, I can't tell due to the missing details. The chapters having a back reference isn't a problem though, it still can be a composition that way - it depends on how you set that reference. For a composition you need to make sure that only the book that references the chapters can be set as a chapter's book reference.

Comment: To expand on my comment: since the diagram you posted doesn't contain an arrow it's perfectly fine for the chapter to have a reference to the book it belongs to. Would it look like `[Book]♦--->[Chapter]` _that_ would mean you can't have that back reference.

Comment: @Thomas and what would happen if that Book inside Chapter was instantiated?

Comment: The Java syntax for declaration of associations, aggregations and compositions is identical: it's just one object having a field that is a reference to another object. The only thing that differentiates them is how you use those fields throughout the code, after they are declared. In your Book class, the `chapters` field denotes composition. In your Chapter class, the `book` field denotes just an association. That's perfectly fine. Though I'd suggest making the `book` field final, since a chapter can never change the book it belongs to.

Comment: @Stultuske as long as book and chapters have the same lifecycle it would still be a composition but implementing it that way would at least be odd and would make me wonder if the model was implemented correctly.

Comment: @Thomas each book has chapters, within each chapter a new Book is instantiated, (which would have chapters, each having a Book, ... )

Comment: @Thomas Rather to use an arrow you should use the dot notation.

Comment: @Stultuske if you'd implement it that way then you'd not be doing it right. As I said, the model states what the code should do and there are various ways of implementing it. The model itself (and composition in general) does _not_ restrict you from having those back references.

Answer (score 5):

That is not enough.

In Composition relationship, If `whole` instance is destroyed, the `part` instance **should also be destroyed immediately**.

You should have some codes (some machanisms) to do that.

For example if you push the instances of `Chapter`s from external the class (for example by using a constructor), you should be careful to delete those instances when the `Book` instance is deleted.

If your instances are created within the `Book` class (by new ...), there is no need to do something and your `Chapter` instances will be deleted with `Book` instance.

In this reference: Object Prime, Third Edition (by Scott W. Ambler, 2004)
in section (**13.4.12.7 Implementing Composition**)

> As you might have guessed, aggregation and composition associations
>   are handled exactly the same way as associations. The main difference,
>   from a programming point-of-view, is aggregation implies a tighter
>   relationship between the two classes than association does, and
>   **composition implies an even tighter relationship still**. Although Fig.
>   13.11 does not include composition associations, the association between Seminar and Course is tight, in fact, at least as tight as you
>   would see with composition (unfortunately the sentence rule does not
>   make sense in this case). In Fig. 13.31, you see the result of this
>   closeness **in the implementation of the remove() method** in the Course
>   class—when a course **is removed**, **its seminars are also removed**. **This**
>   **type of lifecycle management code is typical within composition**
>   **hierarchies**.
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Remove a course
>  *
>  * @postcondition The course and its seminars will be removed
>  */
> public void remove() 
> {
>   if (getSeminars() != null) {
>     // Clone the original set because we can't safely remove
>     // the items from the set while we iterate over it
>     HashSet set = (HashSet) getSeminars().clone();
>     Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
>     // Remove each seminar of this course
>     while (iterator.hasNext()) {
>       Seminar seminar = (Seminar) iterator.next();
>       // Remove the seminar from the collection
>      getSeminars().remove(seminar);
>     }
>   }
>   // Remove the instance from permanent storage
>   // Persistence code ...
> }
> ```

Consider this example:

```
class Person {
   private final Brain brain;
   Person(Brain humanBrain) {
      brain = humanBrain;
   }
}
```

And in other parts of code we can define like this:

```
Brain b = new Brain(); 
       // or we have an instance of Brain in other scopes
       // not exactly in this scope

Person p1 = new Person(b);
Person p2 = new Person(b);
```

So, in this code, we can set one instance of `Brain` to two different `Persons`.

**Note**: In composition, **we should manage the life cycle of instances**. Only defining a `private final` of any class, do not show the Composition between them.

For example the below example can be a Composition. Because instances of `Part` deleted when the `whole` is deleted:

```
public class House {    
   private final Room room;

   public House() {    
       room = new Room();
   }
}
```

**In Composition:** 
The `whole` may directly be responsible for creation or destruction of the `part`. Or it may use a "part" that has been already created and managed from external of class (by other parts of code). In this case, deletion of `part` should be managed by external code and the `part` should be deleted immediately after the `whole` deletion.

We should establish a mechanism to delete `part` when the `whole` is deleted. **If we do not delete the `part` and use it in other `wholes` it is Aggregation or Association**.

Comment: Assuming the Book object is what references the Chapters, the destruction of the Book object would result in garbage collection of the subsequent chapters.

Comment: If the instance pushes from external, and we have another reference in the external the class, that instance will not deleted by whole class.

Comment: so far, we have no evidence that that is the case

Comment: In Object Prime, Third Edition, I will add it to my answer.

Comment: Your first statement is wrong. The association does not forbid a two-way navigation. So you can well have `book` inside `Chapter`.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, thanks, in that case, there is no need to arrow in the Chapter side?

Comment: Don't forget that it is perfectly OK to move a chapter to another book (or have it as a standalone object of the multiplicity to Book allows it) and then delete the book without having to delete said chapter.

Comment: Well, the OP start's from the diagram as given and he wants the implementation. If (and only if) you comment on the diagram, one should use the dot notation (since the reference does really not make sense).

Comment: @GeertBellekens, if it is OK to use an instance of chapter in other books, It it Aggregation.

Comment: @GeertBellekens When I find chapters re-used this is the last book I bought from that author :-D

Comment: I did not say *use*, I said *move*. A chapter is always a part of a single book at a time, but it may move from book to book.

Comment: @GeertBellekens For a reader/buyer that does not make a difference.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I was talking about the specifics of UML compositions, not about books IRL.

Comment: @GeertBellekens, I think that, if in our implementation we **can move** a `Chapter` instance from one `Book` instance to another `Book` instance, **so** in deleting a `Book` instance we can move `Chapter` instances to another too. Therefor that can not be a Composition implementation. But, if in deleting a `Book` instance, we delete all `Chapter` instances too (and do not move them to another classes) it can be Composition implementation.

Comment: Yes, deleting the book should result in deleting all the chapters of the book. But there is no rule that says you can't move chapters to another book.