# UML Diagram Help (Aggregation/Composition)

Tags: java, uml, aggregation, composition

I'm having some trouble fully understanding composition and aggregation. From what i'm understanding a composition relationship means if one dies the other dies. aggregation means they're formed of that, but not necessarily dependent on that things continued existence.

This is the UML I put together for a game of hearts. Am I grasping this concept correctly?
[image: UML Diagram]

Comment: I will tell you that your Card class looks wrong. What are all those integer attributes supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @JimL. Haha i'm working with a pre-defined Card class. I would not have designed it this way, But have to work around this design.

Comment: What tool did you use to draw this diagram, and why does it duplicate the memberName twice for a couple of classes? Doesn't look like real UML.

Comment: I used visio, And it's incomplete. I didn't define the variables and methods yet. I was just trying to get a better understanding of the aggregation/composition types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is composition and aggregation ?**

The composition and aggregation represents a whole/part relationship (UML 2.5, section 11.5.3.1):

> A binary Association may represent a composite aggregation (i.e., a
>   **whole/part relationship**).

So if you use a diamond, you should first ask yourself if it's really a whole/part relationship, before thinking how objects are created or deleted.

Then composition have additional constraints over a shared aggregation. In a composition relationship (UML 2.5, section 9.5.3):

> (...) the composite object has responsibility for the existence and storage
>   of the composed objects. 
>  Composite aggregation is a strong form of
>   aggregation that requires a  part object be included in at most one
>   composite object at a time. If a composite object is deleted, all of
>   its  part instances that are objects are deleted with it.

**Analysis of your specific diagramm**

According to your diagram:

- The *players* exists only within a game (i.e. temporary identification not accounts existing across several games). The composition could make sense, as players can be seen as parts of the game.
- The *hand* exist only in relation to a player. That makes sense. But is it really a composition relationship ?  Is the hand a part of a player ? Is the player composed of hands ? Wouldn't a player have several hands sequentially but not in the same time ?  I really have my doubt about a composition here;  I'd represent this with a normal 1 player to many hands association.
- The game aggregates several *decks*.  I don't know your game but I'd expect one deck.  If several decks are used, and the decks only exists within a game (similarly to the players), I'd rather see a composition instead of an aggregation.  Alternatively you could mean not the deck, but the deck together with its state.  In this case, I'd opt for a one to many association and not a composition (the deck+state would not be a component of your game, but define the state of the game).
- A deck is the aggregation of *cards* that exist independently of the deck.  This troubles me a lot, as my world experience has always shown that a card is part of a deck. If I find an isolated card somewhere I always look for it's deck.  I'd therefore rather expect a composition between cards and deck.
- Finally a hand is the aggregation of several cards, which seems to make sense. Note that this is not incompatible with a composition between the deck and the card.

Comment: Thanks. This helped a ton.

Comment: Your references to UML 2.5 are incomplete. They also, confusingly, say "A part object may be removed from a composite object before the composite object is deleted, and thus not be deleted as part of the composite object". See my SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734891/aggregation-versus-composition/27889087#27889087