# multiplicity of composition relationship

Tags: uml

According to my understanding, a part object can not exist without a composite object. But in this diagram, according to the given multiplicity, B type object can be without A type object. Is it possible? What is the meaning of that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to UML spec (9.5.3)

> Composite aggregation is a strong form of aggregation that requires a part object be included in **at most one** composite object at a time.
>   If a composite object is deleted, all of its part instances that are
>   objects are deleted with it.

The diagram is absolutely correct (you will find such example even on UML exam).

The semantics is that the object of class B - if in composition - is a part of A (A is responsible for B and when A is deleted all objects that are at the moment its parts will be deleted as well). An object of type B that is part of one object of class A cannot simultaneously be a part of other object of type A. However it is possible that is an object of type B that is not a part of any object of type A.

This is your case. So object of type B either is not part of any object of type A (and it is possible in your model) or is a part of exactly one object of type A.

Comment: So how can B have a 0-multiplicity if it's removed when not associated?

Comment: B doesn't have to be a part of A. It can be just a separate object, or can be a part of different object (e.g. C). Moreover the specification doesn't say the element B will be removed when detached from A. It says only that element B will be destroyed if it is a part of A at the moment when A is destroyed. Specification states clearly that it is possible that model can give possibility to detach B from A. If it has to be reattached to other object of type A or can remain a totally separate object depends on model.

Comment: This anwer is correct. It is not required that the a part object (B) is part of an other aggregat object (A). But a part object can only be part of one aggregate objected; irregardless of how many different compositions are defined, as the composition has to be unique.

Comment: It's not true that a composition implies that all components MUST be destroyed when the composite is destroyed, see my SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27889087/2795909

Comment: @gwag, I'm fully aware of this details. Actually the statement in the specification about prior removing of a part from a whole isn't 100% clear as it can be read either that this removal can happen as a step of object destruction or only somewhere in the whole lifecycle before its destruction. Yet if the object was a part and wasn't removed prior to or as a part of destruction process it would be destroyed together with the whole. Which I meant by writing "element B will be destroyed if it is a part of A **at the moment** when A is destroyed".