# Associations between the classes with aggregation

Tags: class, uml, associations, diagram

I need to create an UML Class Diagram and I am not sure if I've done it correctly.

[image]
I will show you on example.
So ClassA has an instance of ClassB and ClassA calls methods from ClassC which take as attributes variables from ClassA and ClassB. Should I connect also ClassC with ClassB? Does the association between ClassA and ClassB should be directed? The implementation of the code below:

```
ClassB {
    constructor() {
        this.str1 = "Hello";
    }
}

ClassA {
    constructor() {
        this.str2 = "World";
        this.objB = new ClassB();
    }
    funA() {
        let objC = new ClassC();
        objC.function1(this.objB.str1);
        objC.function2(this.str2);
    }
}

ClassC {
    constructor() {}
    function1(stringFromB) {
        console.log(stringFromB);
    }
    function2(stringFromA) {
        console.log(stringFromA);
    }
}

let objA = new ClassA();
objA.funA();
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Composite aggregation is about life-time of objects. There's noting in your code that shows a need for that.

[image]

(N.B. I don't know the Java scoping rules so I took `this.objB` as being private.) There's one association which is an owned property of `ClassA` (shown by the dot) named `objB`. The dependency to `ClassC` comes from the (temporarily used) `objC` which is not on class level. It could be discussed whether an association would match (honestly I'd had to dig deeper into the specs), but a dependency isn't wrong in any case (because it's weaker than an association and definitely `A` depends on `B`).

Another N.B. re. your CD: The functions in the code take strings, not objects and one of them misses the trailing `1`.

Comment: Composite aggregation (in the sense of UML) is **NOT** about life-time of objects (this is a widespread misunderstanding resulting from a terminological tradition in the C++ community). Rather, composite aggregation is about the question if parts/components are shareable or not.

Comment: @GerdWagner Read the box on p. 110

Comment: On the same page they say: "NOTE. A part object may (where otherwise allowed) be removed from a composite object before the composite object is deleted, and thus not be deleted as part of the composite object." While the spec is contradictory on the issue of a lifecycle dependency, it is clear on the issue of non-shareabilty of parts. Therefore, lifecycle dependency is **NOT** a defining characteristic, as I have argued in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734891/aggregation-versus-composition/27889087#27889087

Comment: @GerdWagner I'd rather go with the top answer there. Aggregation is just not worth to use it in almost all contexts. So (except you have a definite use) you just should not use it.

Comment: My point is not about using aggregation, but about avoiding to repeat the misconception that "composite aggregation is about life-time of objects", as you have put it.

Comment: @GerdWagner I just think we will not agree. Even a compromise can only be found with a lengthy discussion which will not fit here.

Comment: But this effectively means that you don't want to delete or change your wrong statement ("composite aggregation is about life-time of objects") and you don't want to further justify this (and prefer not to read/understand the arguments provided in the SO answer referenced above).

Comment: Well, how about you? Got fed wisdom with a spoon? Just that you think you are right does not mean you are right.