# If the aggregation is enough or should I connect aggregated classes too

Tags: variables, uml, aggregation

I have a question. If ClassA aggregates ClassB and ClassC and ClassA calls a method of Class C in which it uses attributes from object of ClassB (passed by arguments) should I connect ClassB and ClassC or aggregation is enough?

Image for example:
[Diagram UML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGyGI.png)

Implementation:

```
class ClassA {
    constructor() {
        this.stringA = "Hello"
        this.objB = new ClassB();
        this.objC = new ClassC();
    }
    functionA() {
        this.objB.functionB(this.stringA);
        this.objC.functionC(this.objB.intB);
    }
}

class ClassC {
    constructor() {}
    functionC(intB) {
        console.log(intB);
    }
}

class ClassB {
    constructor() {
        this.intB = 10;
    }
    functionB(stringA) {
        console.log(stringA);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: So what's the difference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54056721/associations-between-the-classes-with-aggregation except that you use another UML notation not matching the code?

Answer (score 0):

In your diagram you use *compositions*, not 'just' *aggregations*, that means the instances of ClassB and ClassC will disappear when the instance of ClassA will disappear.

The goal of the *compositions* and *aggregations* is not to say a class calls a method of an other class or use one of its attribute.

If ClassB uses an attribute of ClassC (already strange, is it public ?) you can use a dependency, but if you add a dependency each time you take the risk to have a dependency between a lot of classes, and the goal of a class diagram is not really to indicate that

Comment: so if I create a getter for intB in ClassB and in functionA I will call that getter (this.objC.functionC(this.objB.getIntB()) I don't need to use a dependency between ClassB and ClassC?

Comment: _functionC receives the value of _this.objB.getIntB()_ in argument, but ClassB don't know that, nor may be ClassC, and this is detail no ? If really the fact a class uses an other one is really important you can indicate that through a dependency, but may be it is is better to define interfaces and components to show require/provide ? A diagram must not be complicated with relations between all as a spider web