# Simple UML class diagram for online shop with one product category

Tags: uml

I'm working on a simple UML class diagram for an online shop with one product category only. I'm not sure how to integrate the classes payments (COD or credit card) and products into my diagram. Diagram see here:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your classes in the plural must be all renamed to singular

The multiplicity of the composition from *Order* to *OrderDetail* must be changed to be `Order <*>-1---------*-> OrderDetail`

It seems logical to have a relation from OrderDetail to *Product*, each *OrderDetail* is associated to one *Product*, and you remove *ProductId* & *ProductName* becoming useless. Not sure *subtotal* has an interest, may be I don't understand well what is the goal.

You can have a relation from *Order* to *Payment*, or may be you can also introduce a class *Bill*  ?

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to what @bruno said I would remove the composite diamond completely since it does not add real value to your model (you can read more about it in the box on p. 110 of the UML 2.5 specs).

As to your main question: `Payment` is an association class to be placed between `Customer` and `Order` and describes the payment details for a single order. Just like so:

[image]

Note the dot. It tells that `orders` is an owned property of `Customer`.

Comment: I also thought about a association-class but that supposes the payment is made at the same time of the order, and I am not sure of that, sometimes the payment is done after the order

Comment: Thanks Bruno & Thomas. I made the proposed amendments - the diagram looks now like that:  [https://www.dropbox.com/s/4w8qriyfgwnh09v/20190107UML.jpg?dl=0] Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Well, you did not read my comment about aggregation. They are just nonsense in your context. Also all those `id` attributes just look like relicts from a database model.

Comment: Which composition would you remove? The order details can not exist without the order class - thought that supposed to be a composition then. 
About the id's - would you remove all except the one from the user class? I'm a bit confused at the moment. Sorry but that UML diagram keeps bothering me since a long time already.

Comment: Be assured that any order you made in a shop still lives, even when your user accounts has been removed. Either for tax purpose or most likely for marketing statistics.  If you clinch on it then leave it. From my POV almost all compositions are just useless. Read @hexagon's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734891/aggregation-versus-composition/