# If a class A contains an array of objects of class B, is the correct UML relationship A depends on B?

Tags: c++, uml

Class A, the registration class contains a private array of objects of class B, the Course class.

Does this mean the registration class depends on the course class, as class A uses class B? Or rather is it an aggregation relationship, as class A has a class B?

```
class Registration {
public:
  Registration();

  unsigned GetCredits() const;
  unsigned GetCount() const;

  friend ostream & operator <<( ostream & os, const Registration & R);

  friend istream & operator >>( istream & input, Registration & R );

private:
  long studentId;             // student ID number
  unsigned semester;          // semester year, number
  unsigned count;             // number of courses
  Course courses[MaxCourses]; // array of courses
};

class Course {
public:
  Course();
  Course( const char * nam, char sect, unsigned cred );

  unsigned GetCredits() const;

  void SetCredits( unsigned cred );

  friend ostream & operator <<( ostream & os, const Course & C );
  friend istream & operator >>( istream & input, Course & C );

private:
  char name[CourseNameSize];  // course name, C style string. not a C++ string object
  char section;   // section (letter) can be enrolment mode
  int  credits;   // number of credits
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230889/difference-between-association-and-dependency

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple association:

[image]

The dot-notation shows that `courses` is an owned property of `Registration`.

Not sure whether it's `0..` or `1..` (probably the latter?).