# What are the terms for writing classes in these fashions?

Tags: terminology

Let's say I have write transformers (e.g. [data presentation layer](https://fractal.thephpleague.com/)) in such ways that the usage looks like these (using PHP syntax):

A: `$userTransformer` can be used for different users, kind of like a helper.

`$userTransformer->transform($user)` // Outputs user data for a webpage

B: `$userTransformer` is specifically for one user.

`$userTransformer->transform()` // Same user output

Are there terms describing the ways these transformer classes are designed? `A` doesn't have any dependency during instantiation, whereas `B` requires `$user` to be instantiated. Personally, I prefer `B`, and I'm trying to look up some literature regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the language of UML, consider the difference between [dependency and association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230889/difference-between-association-and-dependency#answer-1230901).

Dependency:

```
$userTransformer->transform($user) // user is just a method argument
```

Association:

```
$userTransformer->transform() // user is a class field
```

There are two forms of association: [aggregation and composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/what-is-the-difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition/34069760#34069760). Personally, when designing class relationships, I think in terms of "strength of relationships" where:

dependency < aggregation < composition