# What is the type of relationship between an enumeration and a class that produces the enum in one of its methods?

Tags: oop, uml

What is the type of relationship between an enumeration and a class that produces the enum in one of its methods?

E.g Method in Dog creates a Bark enum

[image: UML Diagram]

Note: The enum is **not an attribute of the class**.

Comment: that can be a dependency `<<use>>` but for me it is useless to add a relation because already indicated through the signature of the operation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230889/difference-between-association-and-dependency