# Aggregation and composition - wrong tutorial example

Tags: uml, diagram, composition, aggregation

I find these two examples conceptually identical - yet one is a composition and the other aggregation.

In the [first example](http://javapapers.com/oops/association-aggregation-composition-abstraction-generalization-realization-dependency/), the relationship 'class (has-a) students' is a compositon.

> A class contains students. A student cannot exist without a class.
>   There exists composition between class and students.

In the [second example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation), the relationship 'department (has-a) professors' is an aggregation.

> If the university closes, the departments will no longer exist, but
>   the professors in those departments will continue to exist

In my opinion the first one is plain wrong. Notice that in the comment section of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644273/what-is-the-difference-between-aggregation-composition-and-dependency) SO question @TallPaul is questioning the first example as well.  I think in practice it would delete all students enrolled in a class after each semester from the system. Moreover, the students would probably have to be created by the class on its initialisation, because composition in C++ is usually implemented as private attribute (not pointer). Am I right? Is there any way the first example makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no absolute truth and it all depends on the system you are modeling. You can create a system where students are instances that exist only in a specific class and when the class is deleted, so are the students. This may make sense when you don't want to store student information between classes for example.

Comment: Just rename `student` to `class taker` or something similar and the first example will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those are weak examples, a Class must have a Subject would be a much better example for Composition.  The relationship between a Class and Students is Aggregation because the life-time of the two is different.

See [UML Associations in Java] for more detailed examples[1](http://www.spamer.me.uk/wiki/doku.php/oo_java_uml_association)