# Rhapsody-UML Class Relations

Tags: c++, uml, rhapsody, class-relationship

**What is the difference between association and composition relation ship in uml..**
For Example..

```
class Student
{
Prof p;
//other features..
};
class Prof
{
Student s;
//other features..
};
```

*where above code is an example for composition relationship in c++..*
And in same way what is the coding for association relationship...?
While working **in uml how to implement** this and how to find which relationship should be **prefered**?
In same way how to implement **multiplicity** concept in this relation's...?
**Explain this thing with some real time example as detailed as possible.....**
 Thank u in advance..

Comment: -1 for lack of research effort and unclear goal ("some real time example as detailed as possible")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**composition** is a special kind of **binary association**.

In case of A composed by B, an A instance is responsible to create and destroy B instance; this also means that one instance of B may compose at most one instance of A.

In your code both classes use **composition** but there's an error because there's a **circular composition** (Student needs Prof and Prof needs Student).

Usually a Prof is related to many students and a Student is related to many Profs; in these case you could use **aggregation** in both classes with multiplicity greater than 1.

```
class Student;  // Forward declaration

class Prof {
    std::vector<Student*> _students;
};

class Student {
    std::vector<Prof*> _profs;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Also see [What is the difference between aggregation, composition and dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644273/what-is-the-difference-between-aggregation-composition-and-dependency/1644321#1644321) and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=aggregation+and+composition