# Aggregation vs association in some design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, associations, aggregation

In some class diagram of several design patterns, like decorator pattern for instance, I see an aggregation (between decorator-component) but, in the code, instead having a collection, there is a single variable declared of an interface type.

Why it is an aggregation instead of an association? 
Thank you very much

Comment: You would have to show the diagram you are referring to and also state why you think a collection is needed since a decorator decorates a single component. IMO, there should be composition between decorator and component since they most likely have the same lifecycle, unless you allow to swap the inner component of a decorator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregation is just a form of association. It is commonly defined as a whole-part relationship and this leads to the assumption that aggregation is a one-to-many relationship, which is not necessarily true. Any association or dependency can be a one-to-many relationship, but can also be a one-to-one relationship. Aggregation is no different.

The difference with aggregation is more colloquial, and since many people will *assume* it means one-to-many, you may choose to use it that way; but there is nothing inherently incorrect in a one-to-one aggregation.

You can see some slightly differing views in these references.

- https://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/association-vs-dependency-vs-aggregation-vs-composition/
- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/#N102B7
- [What is the difference between aggregation, composition and dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644273/what-is-the-difference-between-aggregation-composition-and-dependency)