# What's wrong with composition and aggregation?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, aggregation, composition

It's pretty strange to see all those answers about composition/aggregation/association.
Who/What is the source of those notions?

[geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/association-composition-aggregation-java/)

[wikipedia?!?!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)

[stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61376/aggregation-vs-composition)

and finally my lovely stackoverflow (at least I glad that answers were not marked as verified)

[What is the difference between association, aggregation and composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/what-is-the-difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition)

[What is the difference between aggregation, composition and dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644273/what-is-the-difference-between-aggregation-composition-and-dependency)

There is a great book "**Design Patterns**"
[GoF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)

It describes two most common techniques for reusing functionality in object-oriented systems:
1) class inheritance (is-a)
2) object composition (has-a)

> "Object composition is an alternative to class inheritance. Here, new functionality is obtained by assembling or composing objects to get more complex functionality."

"Composition" is a very descriptive term to express relationship between objects unlike "Association".
Why all those sources above use term "Composition" in the wrong way?!

Let's go further.

Objects could be composed in two ways:

1) Aggregation

2) Acquaintance

> "Consider the distinction between object aggregation and acquaintance and how differently they manifest themselves at compile- and run-times. Aggregation implies that one object owns or is responsible for another object. Generally we speak of an object having or being part of another object. Aggregation implies that an aggregate object and its owner have identical lifetimes."

**aggregate** object and its **owner** have identical **lifetimes**!!!

> "Acquaintance implies that an object merely knows of another object. Sometimes acquaintance is called "association" or the "using" relationship. Acquainted objects may request operations of each other, but they aren't responsible for each other. Acquaintance is a weaker relationship than aggregation and suggests much looser coupling between objects."
>
> "It's easy to confuse aggregation and acquaintance, because they are often implemented in the same way. In Smalltalk, all variables are references to other objects. There's no distinction in the programming language between aggregation and acquaintance. In C++, aggregation can be implemented by defining member variables that are real instances, but it's more common to define them as pointers or references to instances. Acquaintance is implemented with pointers and references as well."

Guys, please, help me to figure out what's going on here...

Comment: Many notions of Object relationships come from UML. In practice, I find that distinguishing between them is rarely necessary. On the subject of highly-upvoted misinformation, _welcome to StackOverflow_.

Comment: By the way, this post reads more like a rant than a question. Perhaps you could pinpoint exactly what kind of an answer you're looking for.

Comment: You should also try to quote the relevant bits of the websites you are giving so your post becomes more easily readable.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is lot of confusion around for these two terms *Composition* and *Aggregation* [There is More to add *Shared* and *non-shared* Aggregation]. After going through a lot of confusion and getting biased towards UML resources, I have formed my view as follows [need not be taken as final or accurate].

A simplest and loosely coupled relationship I take is *Association* [it can be *unidirectional* or *bidirectional*] where an Object has a reference of other object but both live independently. Association can be *Qualified Association* if its connected by specific Identity [In OO, identity is an important part of every entity object] e.g. accountNumber for Account of Customer.

*Aggregation* is collection (of other object types and can be assembled for restricted purpose) maintained by an Object. Still both the objects live independently. e.g. Athletics team. Same student can be part of many such teams like Cycling team  [aggregates] and so on. Deleting Athletics team makes no harm to each student entry in college records [they still exist]. Such a relationship can be maintained as Collection of students on Team side or reference of Athletics team for each student being part of team. It depends on more frequently required navigability for application.

*Composition* is more tight relationship where container object completely holds the contained object and contained object does not have any meaning outside relationship with container object. I can see an example as relationship between Person and Address where for each person we keep separate/ fresh entry of address. For family members Address may have same logical equality, but never physical equality. Change of address for one member does not affect other members [simple test is - DB columns for Person record has extended columns for address as a part of person table.] another example is Single entry (row) of item purchase and Complete bill of items. where deleting bill makes each entry context-less.

If an object instantiates and contains another object completely [never allows outside world to obtain its ref by any means] I would take that as Composition. Techniques like Cloning objects at interaction points instead of passing same ref can be helpful here. In case of association or aggregation, we exchange same reference.

*Containment* being *black-box* reuse, is preferred over *white-box* kind of reuse (implemented using *inheritance*). Most of the GOF patterns suggest best combinations of Containment for reuse and inheritance for polymorphism. e.g. In case of Adapter pattern, *Object Adapter* is preferred over *Class Adapter*.

Implementing all these flavors in Java (Implementations will be language specific) has its own challenge and NOT very straight forward, especially *composition*. There is a point on learning curve, where one feels (at least I felt) *Composition* is same as *inner class*, inner class can help us implement it, but simply having inner class does not give any guarantee of composition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Could you also please share your vision of term that expresses relationship between object and included object(s).
GoF uses term Composition "new functionality is obtained by composing objects to get more complex functionality".
I don't understand why the whole world uses Patterns from GoF but deny pretty straightforward terms like Composition, Aggregation and Acquaintance(association)?

Comment: @Konstantin, I have edited my answer to accomodate your above point. UML uses these terms and clearly differentiates between those.