# Composition vs Bi-directional Association in Java

Tags: java, associations, composition

I understand the differences in theory, but what is the difference in the code implementation? Can somebody provide some examples?

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298177/association-vs-aggregation (third answer) also helped.

I have a final uncertainty I hope someone can address.
Am I correct in believing instances of the associated class in this diagram http://img152.imageshack.us/img152/4981/21083939.png would have to be owned by a class not shown in the diagram (otherwise an aggregate relationship would have to exist between whole and associated class?)?

Answer (score 3):

Purpose we have students and universities

```
class University {
    private final Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();
    void addStudent(Student s){students.add(s);}
}

class Student {
    private final String name;
    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

We create this stuff in some way

```
University university = new University();
Student bob = new Student("Bob");
university.addStudent(bob);
```

And know we need to know does Bob studies in university.
So we create some new method for university

```
boolean contains(Student student){
        for(Student s : students){
            if(s.equals(student)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and, than do smt like `university.contains(bob)`.

But what will be if we havent link to uniwersity. We need to ask it Bob. But Bob doesn't know. So we go from composition to bi-derection and create smt like

```
class University {
    private final Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();
    void addStudent(Student s){
        students.add(s);
        s.setUniversity(this);
    }
    boolean contains(Student student){
        for(Student s : students){
            if(s.equals(student)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class Student {
    private final String name;
    private University university;
    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    void setUniversity(University u){
        university = u;
    }
    boolean doYouStudyInUniversity(){
        return university != null;
    }
}
//ask
bob.doYouStudyInUniversity();
```

Comment: Should we enforce the setUniversity and addStudent in the constructor to make sure that they will always be called when a new Student is created?

Comment: @Kenston Choi, it depends from your coding style/paradigm you are using. Anyway it quite challenging to construct immutable bidirectional structures in Java (you can imitate it using proxies).

Answer (score 0):

Composition is, in effect, uni-directional association - except that semantically, we interpret it as meaning "that thing is part of this thing" rather than simply "this thing holds a reference to that thing".