# Code of Association, Composition and Aggregation

Tags: c#, associations, aggregation, composition

I read many times about Association, Composition and Aggregation. What will the simple code in c# of these three terms? I have understood about the difference of Composition and Aggregation, but in Association, its look like just Composition in my view. I am just beginner of c#, sorry if i wrote here something wrong about these terms.

Comment: simple saying `I read many times about ... Please explain ...` is usually not enough. Quoting internet without providing quote source will not lead to informative answers. Of course some terms do not need further explanation but out of those three some may be treated differently by different people.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# code for association, aggregation, composition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604031/c-sharp-code-for-association-aggregation-composition)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between association, aggregation and composition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a reasonable question.  In fact, it's been asked and answered rather well, including code examples, in this StackOverflow thread: [Difference between association, aggregation and composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Micheal, but i want C# examples of these three terms, i think your link has c++ examples.