# C# code for association, aggregation, composition

Tags: c#, oop, uml, class-diagram

I am trying to confirm my understanding of what the code would look like for association, aggregation & composition. So here goes.

**Aggregation**: Has-a. It *has* an existing object of another type

```
public class Aggregation
{
    SomeUtilityClass objSC
    public void doSomething(SomeUtilityClass obj)
    {
      objSC = obj;
    }
}
```

**Composition**: Is composed of another object

```
public class Composition
{
    SomeUtilityClass objSC = new SomeUtilityClass();
    public void doSomething()
    {
        objSC.someMethod();
    }
}
```

**Association**: I have two views on this.

1. When one class is associated with another. Hence both the above are examples of association.
2. Association is a weaker form of Aggregation where the class doesn't keep a reference to the object it receives.

   ```
   public class Association
   {
       //SomeUtilityClass objSC   /*NO local reference maintained */
       public void doSomething(SomeUtilityClass obj)
       {
          obj.DoSomething();
       }
   }
   ```

Is my understanding correct? I have read conflicting articles [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pcurnow/compagg07272007062838AM/compagg.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/330447/Understanding-Association-Aggregation-and-Composit) and so I am really not sure which one to follow. My understanding seems to be in line with the first link. I feel the second link is wrong, or maybe perhaps I haven't understood it properly.

What do you think?

Comment: aggregation and association are not commonly used terms in my experience.  I wouldn't fuss too much about knowing the subtleties of their definition.  There are much more interesting concepts for you to spend your time on.

Comment: thanks Servy; but is my understanding described above correct?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pcurnow/compagg07272007062838AM/compagg.aspx

Comment: @Servy I know this is an old article but I have been struggling with same issue for sometimes as I am learning on my own. I was wondering, based on your comment above, what concepts would you suggest to learn?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The difference between aggregation and composition is pretty fuzzy and AFAIK relates to the logical existence of the "child" objects after the container is destroyed. Hence, in the case of aggregation the objects inside the container can still exist after the container object is destroyed, while in the case of composition design demands that they also get destroyed. Some analogies:

- A `Car` object containing four `Wheel` objects. Normally if you destroy the car (by calling some method to clean it up) you should also destroy the wheels in the process, since it makes little sense for them to exist outside the car (unless you move them to another `Car` object). More realistically, a reader object wrapping an input stream will also close the inner stream when it gets closed itself. This is **composition**.
- A `Person` object contains (owns) a `Radio` object. If the `Person` dies, the `Radio` may be inherited by another `Person` i.e. it makes sense for it to exist without the original owner. More realistically, a list holding objects does not demand that all objects get disposed when the list itself is disposed. This is **aggregation**.

**Edit**: After reading your links I'd be inclined to go with the first one, since it gives an explanation similar to mine.

Also **association** is merely invoking a method (sending a message) to another object via a reference to that object.

Comment: @user20358: Association is generally defined as calling a method on another object. It doesn't matter if you keep a reference of not. Technically you can have aggregation without association: just hold some objects but don't use them for anything. :D

Comment: Good examples...very helpfull.

Answer (score 69):

For two objects `Foo` and `Bar` we have:

**Dependency:**

```
class Foo
{
    ...
    fooMethod(Bar bar){}
    ...
}
```

**Association:**

```
class Foo
{
    private Bar bar;
    ...
}
```

**Composition:** (When `Foo` dies so does `Bar`)

```
class Foo
{
    ...
    private Bar bar = new Bar();
    ...
}
```

**Aggregation:** (When `Foo` dies, `Bar` may live on)

```
class Foo 
{
    private List<Bar> bars;
}
```

Comment: Association sample just different in multiplicity with Aggregation sample! Bar vs List<Bar>, So do you mean any association with more than one object reference is Aggregation?

Comment: First of all **agregation** is a particular case of **assotiation**. When you use assotiation you just want _has-a_ relationship between `Foo` and `Bar`. But if you want _has-a_ + _whole-part_ relationships between `Foo` and `Bar` the you use aggregation. You use **composition** if you want that _Foo_ and _Bar_ have _has-a_ + _whole-part_ + _ownership_ relationship.

Comment: @AndritchiAlexei How whole- part relationship affects the code? For has-a it is clear, there is a class member, for ownership relationship it is as well clear, there is an object creator.

Answer (score 4):

If inheritance gives us `'is-a'` and composition gives us `'part-of'`, we could argue that aggregation gives us a `'has-a'` relationship.

==> In short, *Association, Aggregation, and Composition are terms that represent relationships among objects*.

1. **Association**: Association means that an object `"uses"` another object. As you said: *"Association is a weaker form of Aggregation where the class doesn't keep a reference to the object it receives."*

```
public class Association
{
    //SomeUtilityClass _obj   /*NO local reference maintained */
    public void doSomething(SomeUtilityClass obj)
    {
       obj.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

2. **Aggregation**:

- Aggregation is a special type of Association.
- Aggregation is `"has-a"` relationship among objects `(white diamond)`
- For example, *Person 'has-a' Address*.

```
public class Address  
{  
 . . .  
}  
public class Person  
{  
     private Address address;  
     public Person(Address address)  
     {  
         this.address = address;  
     }  
     . . .  
}
```

As you can see, the *Person* does not manage the lifetime of *Address*. If the Person is destroyed, the Address still exists.

[image]

3. **Composition**:

- Composition is a special type of Aggregation, It is a strong type Aggregation.
- Composition gives us a `'part-of'` relationship`(dark diamond)`. Ex: Engine is part-of a car

```
public class Engine  
{  
 . . .   
}  
public class Car  
{  
    Engine e = new Engine();  
    .......  
}
```

[image]

Please, prefer the links below to get future information:

- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/association-aggregation-and-composition/
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/difference-between-composition-and-aggregation/

Answer (score 1):

In Aggregation and Composition you are right but in Association it's not correct.
what you suppose about association in your example is dependency in fact.

But what is Association realy?

From Object-Oriented Analysis and Design with Applications By  Grady Booch  :

> Of these different kinds of class relationships, associations are the most general
> but also the most semantically weak. The identification of associations among
> classes is often an activity of analysis and early design, at which time we begin to
> discover the general dependencies among our abstractions. As we continue our
> design and implementation, we will often refine these weak associations by turning them into one of the other more concrete class relationships