# How to implement Aggregation and Association in Code?

Tags: java, c#, associations, aggregation

What is it like **Aggregation** and **Association** in Code?(Java or C#)
I can't find the code examples of Aggregation and Association.

Answer (score 1):

**Association** example: Employee has Address

```
public class Employee  
{         
   public Address address; //Employee HAS-A Address  
}
```

**Aggregation** example: Employee has many Address

```
public class Employee  
{         
  public List<Address> address; //Employee HAS-Many Address  
}
```

See: [C# code for association, aggregation, composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604031/c-sharp-code-for-association-aggregation-composition)

Comment: Does it mean that when we use Composition or Dependency, Association is already involved?

Comment: @Aoi see this post: https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/uml-aggregation-vs-composition/