# OOD and object ids

Tags: oop, identity

My application manages fruit records. The application supports different types of data sources. Each fruit has a unique id in the data source. Uniqueness across data sources is not guaranteed because I don't have control over those ids.

I have created a `class FruitSourceManager{}` that allows we to configure (add/remove) the different fruit sources in my application.

I also have `class BasketFruitSource{}` 
`class CartFruitSource{}`
`class TruckFruitSource{}` each of which implements the
`interface IFruitSource{}`

I have a
`class FruitManager{}`
which provides CRUD operations on the Fruit by invoking operations on the IFruitSource

And then I have a
`class Fruit{}` which is used at the business layer and a `class FruitDTO{}` which is used by the web service.

The application exposes a web service that allows you to read or modify a fruit record. 
    `GetFruitById()`
    `UpdateFruit()`

Is it ok to concatenate the FruitSourceId with the FruitId as a single ID used in the FruitDTO? Or should I use two parameters (FruitSourceId and FruitID) uniquely identifying the fruit?

Are there any pros and cons to one versus the other? Or am I splitting hairs here?

Comment: Why is this tagged with c# and java?

Comment: That's what being used in the project. But yes, this could apply to any other language. I updated the tags.

Comment: What is the relation between IFruitSource and Fruit? I would guide my decision on how to manage the Ids based on this information. [Association, aggregation or composition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition) One-to-many or one-to-one?

Comment: It's an aggregation. A Fruit belongs to one IFruitSource only but is not tied to the lifecycle of the IFruitSource.

Comment: What if a IFruitSource is removed? The related Fruit instances keep living with a NULL IFruitSource?

Comment: A Fruit object make sense without a Source. However, it comes from a source and cannot be saved/modified without it. There can be a Fruit without a Source assigned but only temporarily until it is saved into one of the sources.

Comment: Can you have multiple BasketFruitSource instances, or just one? The same question applies to CartFruitSource, TruckFruitSource, and whatever other implementations you have...

Comment: He removed his tags :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what kind of id's you have for the fruits. If your ids are fixed length you could theoretically concatenate them but for incrementing numbers absolutely not

-->
123 + 1 = 12 + 31 
etc...

Better ID them yourself if you cant influence your suppliers ids. who knows what kind of strange id (ordering number?) another supplier will have in the future.

Comment: Yes, the supplier ids could be anything. So what I'm thinking about is to have fixed width source id followed by the supplier id. Or maybe use a separator character instead.

Comment: supplier id is another name for source id?

Comment: Yes supplier == source