# best way to add relation between tables in sql

Tags: sql, database

i have four tables company,subcompany,form and cargo
each company contains several subcompanies and each subcompany contains forms
and each form contains cargoes

i need queries to get fomrs of a company, forms of subcompany, cargos of a company, cargos of sub company

my question is **Which relationship is better?** i choos secound one because i think its easier to query and faster.

1. add only relations between

   Company ----> SubCompany -------> Form ------> Cargo
   [Image1](http://postimg.org/image/vwitqfkuf/)
2. add relation between company and all three tables, relation between subcompany and two other tables, and relation between form and cargo.
   [Image2](http://postimg.org/image/ha6mhd1yv/)

Comment: The first one is better. The second one contains redundant information, which is generally a bad thing, although sometimes this *denormalizing* is done when it is really needed for speed, but you probably won't need it. A normal database doesn't have problems with 3 joins. If it does, improve it in other ways while keeping the relations normalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `Form` and `Cargo` have a [`composition association`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition) and `SubCompany` and `Form` also have a composition association thus there should be a one to many relationship between them.
So far your number 1 design seems better but the question is what's the relationship between `Company` and `Form` ? If a `SubCompany` can have forms will a `Company` can have `Forms` also ? (Having `Forms` is a feature of a `Company` or its `SubCompany`?) If `Company` can't have `Forms` itself then number 1 seems to be a reasonable design but if it can then may be you should change it a little bit some thing like this :

```
Company has a one to many self relation (Sub Company)
Company has a one to many relation with Form
Form has a one to many relation with Cargo
```

In this design there's no individual entity for `SubCompany` each `Company` that has a parent `Company` is a `SubCompany` of that Company

Comment: no a company cant have forms, but there is alot of companies that are getting report of their subcompany forms every 10 secends, so i decide to add a relationship between company and form to query and show forms of sub companies to companies faster, but it seems i was wrong

Comment: Perhaps you'd better have a view that shows each form for each company according to its sub companies.