# Inheritance example of a real world tree

Tags: inheritance

I do have a basic question about inheritance and classes.

How would you create an real world object of a tree (a real tree).

Tree should have branches, branches should have leaves.

So:

```
class Tree {
// something about a tree itself
}

Class Branch : Tree {
//something about a branch
}

Class Leaf : Branch {
//something about a leaf
}
```

But now, should a tree class know about all the branches instances and create all the branches objects itself while the branches should create leaves for themselves and also know about them ?

So to just put a tree you would:

```
Tree myNewTree = new Tree(); // or something like that ?
```

I think i got something back to front here... Examples of a shape - > rectangle and you ask for rectangle makes sense.

Comment: Inheritance is the wrong approach here.  A branch is not a kind of tree, and a leaf is not a kind of branch.

Comment: What approach would be appropriate here ?

Comment: Go for Composition instead of Inheritance

Comment: the tree here is an object. you must have only one class. branch and leaf can be either a variable or an array. it depends on your case here.

Comment: So, should I have a class of branch and a class of leaf, and then array of branches within a tree data ?

Comment: What you want is *composition* or maybe *aggregation*, not *inheritance*. Take a look at this link [from stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition) or this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep#Composition)

Comment: Thank you @HaroldShip I've looked into those and all is quite clear right now. If a tree would die within all branches and leaves and those branches and leaves only works with a tree that should be composition, but if branches and leaves could live on without a tree for a while that would be aggregation am I right ?

Comment: @Tomas you are right. If they do not exist without the tree then composition. If the leaves continue to live without the tree then aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have following structure

```
class Tree {
// something about a tree itself
        Branch b[];
        Leaf lf[];
}

Class Branch {
    //something about a branch
}

Class Leaf{
  //something about a leaf
}
```

If you want to restrict Branch and Leaf of type tree then Extend Tree class in above structure and Compose them in your Tree Class according to real world Scenario.

Here i have used array you can use anything else like ArrayList <E> or Simple object depending upon your requirement.

Comment: I did understand almost all of this from the comments, but what do you mean by saying "extend tree class in above structure" ?

Comment: That simply means when you still want your branch and leaf should be inherited from Tree.Then inherit Tree class for Branch and Leaf.

Comment: I feel like the leaves should be a property of a branch, not the tree.

Comment: @bwroga it is in my example.

Comment: @Tomas, the comment was intended for user2408578.

Comment: @bwroga Yes then that can also be composed in Branch class like    Class Branch{ Leaf l[]; / List<Leaf> l; }