# How to get value property from another class without inheritance in C#

Tags: c#

I have classes:

```
public class Employee{

 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Firstname {get;set;}

}

public class Person
{
   //get value Firstname property from Employee class
     Employee emp = new Employee();
     foreach(var s in emp)
     {
       Console.WriteLine(s.Firstname.ToList());
     }

}
```

So, I want to get value of property ex: Firstname from Person class.

(I'm newbie in C#)

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you any instance of `Employee` in `Person` class? If yes - then just access that instance `Firstname` property.

Comment: As your `Employee` isnt static, you need to create an instance out of it.

Comment: this isn't a teaching site and this is a very basic question. read up on C# and learn a little. By the power of google I summon thy teaching sites! https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=learn%20c%23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition) (it's when Employee knows about Person and cannot operate without it). Example :

```
public class Employee
{    
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Firstname => Person.FirstName;
   public Person Person {get;private set;}

   // this ctor is set to private to prevent construction of object with default constructor
   private Employee() {}

   public Employee(Person person) 
   { 
       this.Person = person;
   }
}

public class Person
{
   // We add property to Person as it's more generic class than Employee
   public string Firstname {get;set;}
}
```

To create Employee you can use this code :

```
var jon = new Person { FirstName = "Jon" };
var employee = new Employee(jon);
Console.WriteLine(employee.FirstName); // OR
Console.WriteLine(employee.Person.FirstName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `FirstName` property is a string type so you can not interate over it by foreach loop you can only access it by this way

```
public class Employee{

 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Firstname {get;set;}

 public Employee(string name)
 {
   this.Firstname = name;
 }

}

public class Person
{
   Employee emp = new Employee("Foo");
   string s = emp.Firstname;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but Firstname property shows  still null  :(

Comment: you need to first set the FirstName anywhere in the code then you will get the value, try updated one