# POCO objects to UML representation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, uml, poco

I want to correctly represent my POCO classes of Entity Framework in UML diagram.
For instance, I have the following relationships :

```
public class SchoolGroup {
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public string GroupName {get;set;}
     public Subject GroupSubject {get;set;}
     public Teacher GroupTeacher {get;set;}
     public ICollection<Student> AttendeeStudents {get;set;}
}
```

Here we see that School Group Entity contains of instances of Subject, Teacher and a collection of Students.

According to this post [Difference between association, aggregation and composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition) :

**Association** - I have a relationship with an object.  Foo uses Bar.

**Composition** - I own an object and I am responsible for its lifetime, when Foo dies, so does Bar.

**Aggregation** - I have an object which I've borrowed from someone else. When Foo dies, Bar may live on.

So, how should I represent my **SchoolGroup** in UML notation : will it be a composition or an aggregation?

Comment: You have to think about it in terms of the real world. Assuming you can think of a SchoolGroup as a school, if that school closes down, will the teachers have jobs left, and will there be any subjects or students attending it anymore? From what I can understand, you want to use composition.

Comment: I would just not use it. Comp/Aggr is meaningful in DB design to set constraints and for memory management (which today is becoming a don't-care). The semantics of those is near to nil else.