# aggregation vs composition explaination

Tags: uml, aggregation, composition

I have done some research and googled a lot. I have some confusion to confirm either my scenarios are correct or not.

Here is first question:

With reference to Figure down, what do you think is the most likely implementation of the relationship between Car and Passengers? Choose only one option

[image]

```
          A.          Inheritance
          B.          Association
          *C.        Aggregation
          D.          Composition
```

So, the answer is Aggregation as I understand the scenario and googled but I need confirmation from other developers.

Here is second question:

With reference to Figure down, what do you think is the most likely implementation of the relationship between Apple and Fruit?

[image]

```
          A.          Inheritance
          B.          Association
          C.          Aggregation
          *D.         Composition
```

So, the answer is Composition I understand the scenario and googled but I need confirmation from other developers.

All these above questions are from well knows internet sites, now I am confuse what is the logic behind it.

Regards

Comment: No. Apple inherits from Fruit because Apple IS A Fruit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Comment: I am not sure that we can answer to the question, of course the remark of @Kilian about inheritance is meaning full, but the choice between association or composition depends on the context ... And you should avoid aggregation which is not well defined in UML. You knonw, on stackoverflow there are a lot's of questions about this topic ...

Comment: @granier I did not moan the composition, although you are right. The problem is that teachers still believe that there is some semantics because in the past UML version were wishy washy here.

Comment: You're right, some teachers are not up-to-date :) all students know that :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between association, aggregation and composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/what-is-the-difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition)