# Correct way of implementing composition (Composition with interface )

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I am confused with these implementations .In an interview,interviewer asked me what is composition and I gave him typical  definition then I wrote this part of code for him.

```
public class Foo {
    private Bar bar = new Bar(); 
}
```

But he claimed this  implementation is correct

```
interface IFoo
{
    int DoSomthing();
}

class Bar : IFoo
{
    public int DoSomthing()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Which one is correct?

Comment: Second one is just a class implementing an interface. I don't see composition there. This should help https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/association-composition-aggregation-java/

Comment: I'm not the person who downvoted you, but it may have been because you don't show that you took any effort to research the composition-over-inheritance principle before asking a question here.  Your first code example doesn't have anything to do with composition.

Comment: Read [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), the first paragraph and the first example will probably make it click.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I realize now that both you and your interviewer were correct; answer updated accordingly.

From the wikipedia page on [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance):

> Composition over inheritance...is the principle that classes should achieve polymorphic behavior and code reuse by their composition (**by containing instances of other classes that implement the desired functionality**) rather than inheritance from a base or parent class.

[Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) is

> the provision of a single interface to entities of different types.

So what you did (having `Bar` be a property of `Foo`) is Composition because `Bar` has an instance of `Foo` through having it as a property.

What your interviewer did was also Composition because, through the interface `IFoo`, `Bar` implements the same functionality, and it didn't use inheritance to do so.  This appears to be the way it's documented on the linked wiki page but doesn't mean your way is wrong either.

Which method you use for implementing the same functionality in different places would depend on whether it makes sense for `Bar` to be a property of `Foo` or not.

Comment: so,you mean  he was right?so why in many websites they use the code I wrote in that interview.could you provide some peace of code

Comment: @E_N_Y give me a link and I'll look into it.

Comment: [What is the difference between association, aggregation and composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/what-is-the-difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition)

Comment: So next time I should describe both cases!

Answer (score 2):

Composition denotes a "is-a-part-of" relationship between objects. For example,

```
class Engine
{
    //....
}

class Car
{
    Engine engine = new Engine();
    //.....
}
```

we can see, Engine is-a-part-of Car. Composition and inheritance are two different concepts and you probably shouldn't accept a job offer where he would be your boss.  :)

Comment: In your example Car doesn't actually implement Engine, it just has a property of type Engine.  The [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) principle is about ways to introduce polymorphic behavior, so in other words where Car implements things from Engine.

Comment: I am realizing that your method is actually an example of composition as well (and have updated my answer accordingly) but SO isn't letting my remove my downvote from your answer unless the answer is edited.

Comment: @levininja just edited it!