# Spring DI : Aggregation or Composition

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

**Aggregation:** If two objects have there own life cycle and not tightly coupled with each other(can exists independently).

```
Class A {
    B b;
}
```

The default value for `b` will be `null` and `A's` object can exists if there is no instance injected in A.

**Composition:** if two objects are tightly coupled and one can not exists without second.

```
Class A{
   B b;
   A(B b){
      this.b = b;
    }
}
```

**Spring DI:** In spring if we are using `@Autowired` annotation over a member then this member is required before instantiation of object.

```
Class A{
  @Autowired  */ now this member is required before creating of object of A.
  B b;
}
```

**Query:** So from the above facts we can think `Spring DI` as a composition here .I am asking this question because in a interview I had a discussion over it and as per the interviewer `Spring` is using `Aggregation` here. 
Could any one please clarify if I am missing or not getting some thing here.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's depend on B scope. If B is singletone then B manage itslef life cycle, so the relation between A and B is Aggregation.
If B is not singletone (prototype) then every time A is creating a new instance of B created and injected into A and A manage B life cycle, so the relation between A and B in this scenario ll be Composition

Comment: but anyhow object of 'A' can not be exists with the object of 'B' and if the B's scope is singleton then also at the first `getBean` call B will going to instantiate.

Comment: your definition about Composition is wrong. take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/what-is-the-difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition

Comment: I am not sure why you are saying it wrong, try to take it as (A -> Address and B-> City).

Comment: City is parent and Address is child, you should say A-> City and B-> Address. if we think A as child and B as parent existence of A is always depend on B.

Answer (score 0):

I think, in `Spring` `Autowire` means more `Aggregation` when classes service each other.

For example in `MVC` design pattern  in Service layer . you may have  two Service  class that service each other.like `Teacher` that teach student and `Student` learn from teacher.for implement sample like this you should have two classes like below:

```
Class Teacher(){
     public void teach(Lesson lesson,Student student){
      //...
     }
}

Class Student(){
     @Autowire
     private ITeacher iTeacher;

     public void learn(Lesson lesson){
       iTeacher.teach(lesson,this);
       //...
     }
}
```

As you see `Student` depends to `interface` of `Teacher`. and `Spring` choose which implement of `Interface` choose for injection.From this point of view, beans not coupled together and you can remove and replace implementation by another.

Answer (score 0):

To understand it first you should understand how spring bean is created and who maintains the lifecycle of spring bean(https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html), Spring bean instance is created by spring IOC container, and it's created when you start your application so there is loose coupling between your classes(because dependcy bean can exist without the second class exist)

```
Class A{
  @Autowired  */ if B is bean class then it's created eagrly by spring IOC container, so object b is not created by class A.
  B b;
}
```

so I can say your interviwer is right in saying that spring is using Aggregation here not composition

PS - just make sure class A and class B is bean class