# UML relationship of class and object it creates inside the creation of another object?

Tags: java, uml, instantiation, class-diagram

For example, in java:

```
public class App {

    public void method() {

        Object1 o1 = new Object1(new Object2(parameters));
    }

}
```

I know App and Object1 have a composition relationship.

But what about App and Object2? Is it a composition as well?

Comment: Both are dependencies, not compositions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/what-is-the-difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition

Comment: Is it because Object2 is used in `method` that it's a dependency relationship? So if o1 was created as a variable outside `method` then it would be a composition? @GeertBellekens

Comment: It's only a composition if there is a *structural* relation. The relation here is temporary, and exists only during the execution of `method`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between association, aggregation and composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/what-is-the-difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition)

Comment: Definitely helped, along with this article: http://usna86-techbits.blogspot.com/2012/11/uml-class-diagram-relationships.html

Comment: One thing though, what, to you, distinguishes associations from aggregations when implementing code? Also, thanks a bunch @GeertBellekens

Comment: Aggregations have (almost) no technical impact. They are mostly a functional concept. The only real constraints for aggregation are: have to be binary (only two ends) and they have to be acyclic (so they cannot become a part of themselves)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using a class in a method is not sufficient for an association

Your class `App` has no fields of class `Object1` or  `Object2`.  It just uses `Object1` and `Object2` in the implementation of a method.  This is not sufficient for making an association: there is no conceptual relationship between `App`  and `ObjectX`; it's just an implementation detail.   And since composition is a special kind of association, there is no composition either.

### Using a class means a dependency

Since your `App` uses `Object1` and `Object2`,  there is a `«use»` [dependency](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html?context=class-diagrams):  `App` needs to know these classes. You could show this dependency with an open headed dashed arrow.

However, the dependency in your example is only at the level of the method implementation and not at the level of the class itself.  You could implement the method otherwise. I'd therefore advise not to show such a volatile dependency in your model.  The dependency would be advisable if the class definition itself would use such an object (e.g. if a method would return an `ObjectX` or use an `ObjectX` parameter).

### Terminology: Not all compositions are compositions!

As explained,  there is no composition here.  Nevertheless, the word is ambiguous:

- it could mean [object compostion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).  This is just about objects having fields of another class.
- it could mean [UML composition](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/composition.html?context=class-diagrams). This is a special kind of association with exclusive ownership

Comment: Thanks @Christophe. "I'd therefore advise not to show such a volatile dependency in your model" 
Regarding it being 'volatile'; would a nonvolatile implementation be to turn it into an actual composition relationship between App and Object1?

Comment: @AMoses no, I used the term "volatile" to mean that the implementation could change independently of the class’ structural characteristics. Your method implementation describes a behavior of the class, and a class diagram describes the structure of the classes independently of their behaviors.

Comment: UML 2.5 does not have «use» but only `Usage`. This is heritage, isn't it?

Comment: @qwerty_so You really made me hesitate.  I think the "usage dependency" is still noted with a `«use»` label on the dashed dependency line. I preferred to provide the ready to use keyword between guillemet rather than the metamodel element without guillemet in my answer.  I don't think it's heritage, unless page 746 of the UML 2.5.1 specs was replaced without me noticing.

Comment: @qwerty_so now I'm reinsured:  page 39,  there is a caption:  "Figure 7.20 An example of a «use» Dependency" ;-)

Comment: The missing glossary in the UML specs is a real PITA. A bit above the picture it states _A Usage is shown as a Dependency with a «use» keyword attached to it._ That keyword itself is not explained like e.g. `trace`. Well...