# UML- Composition and Inheritance at Once

Tags: inheritance, uml, composition

I am creating UML diagrams for others' code, and I encountered something peculiar- a child class has a parent class as one of its member variables, seemingly both a "has a" and an "is a" relationship. Apparently, this is intentional, but even after looking through UML guides, I'm still lost on how to even represent this. Do I only show Inheritance, the stronger relationship? Do I overlay the arrows, creating a solid white arrowhead with a line through it?

With replaced class names in Java:

```
public abstract class A {
}

public abstract class B extends A {
    protected A a;
}
```

How would I represent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two different relations, so you simply just show them both

[image]

From the code alone there is no evidence that the `Association` between B and A is also a `Composition`, so I kept it to a plain association.
There are a few questions here that explain the differences between associations and compositions quite nicely e.g.
[What is the difference between association, aggregation and composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/what-is-the-difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition)

The fact that both classnames are in *Italics* indicates the fact that they are both declared *Abstract*

Comment: You might want to show the role too. And indicate the use of italics. And maybe link to an "composition" answer...