# Composition and aggregation issue Java

Tags: java, uml, aggregation, composition, class-diagram

Can someone please explain me what is type of aggregation is and why for that the vector should not be initialized and this code is according to diagram? What I don't understand why when is -> at the end of aggregation or composition the vector shouldn't be internalized.

```
class Project
{
 private Vector<Student> stds;
 private Vector<Diag> diagra = new Vector();
}
```

UML:[image]

Comment: What about is your question, UML or Java?

Comment: @qwerty_so both, 1. what is the difference betwenn aggregation\compozition with ---- and ----->
2. why for first is inot ntantiated the vector and for the second  is ?

Comment: I would have closed your question re UML since https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/what-is-the-difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition Asking 2 questions in one is not a good fit here. Anyhow, since Christophe has already given an answer re Java I'll leave it as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does not allow to make a difference between association, aggregation, composition. The initialization or not of the vector is not relevant.

The UML says that a `Project` has an unspecified number of `Student`. Since it is aggregation, there is no exclusive ownership, sot the same students can appear in several projects. ALsi, when the project is destroyed,  all its students remain unaffected.

- The Java code leaves `stds` unitialized.  This says nor guarantees anything about ownership of the Student.
- Moreover, the Java code will have at one moment or the other to properly initialize the `stds` vector if the project is supposed to aggregate some students.
- In fact, I suspect the author of the code to confuse aggregation with the object assignment in Java. Aggregation is a modeling placebo that does not have this meaning. It is much simpler and less ambiguous to use a simple association instead of an agregation in this case.

The UML says the a `Project` is a composite that has an unspecified number of `Diag`. The composition means an exclusive ownership, not of the vector, but of the diagrams that are stored within:

- The java code uses vector that is initialized to an empty vector, which tells nothing about teh lifeclycle and ownership of the objects it will contain.
- In fact, the vector elements are references (“object handles”) that can always be shared. Nothing guarantees the ownership of the diagrams in the code.