# Can an association be non-composition and non-aggregation?

Tags: oop, associations, aggregation, composition

I have heard that aggregation and composition are parts of association (If we are talking about OOP). But there is a occasions where we can't name one like an assotiation or aggregation?

I've read similar questions on this site and have searched in the Internet already

*P.S. I'm sorry for my English grammary; It's not my relative language*

Comment: Short answer: yes.   But this is not a Java question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937.

Comment: @StephenC however, I cannot imagine a situation like that... Might you give an example?

Comment: Well ... the association between a person and their parents (and children) is neither composition or aggregation. Marriage is another example.

Answer (score 0):

As @StephenC said:

> The association between a person and their parents (and children) is
> neither composition or aggregation. Marriage is another example.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).