Why using association?
I am currently learning about UML class diagrams. I have learned that an association just shows that "There is a relationship between these classes". Meanwhile, composition and aggregation show that "The relationship of these classes must like this", which is adding specific information to the association. I don't know why we keep using association.  Isn't it more specific to use composition or aggregation instead ? If no, in what scenario we should use association over the other 2 ?
Hope someone can explain this for me.

There are many cases where you would use an association that is neither a composition or an aggregation.
Consider a many-to-many Likes association between Person and Food.  This is neither composition or aggregation.
Having said that, the aggregation semantics (aggregate, composite or none) are often contextual and/or debatable.  For example, consider a ParentChild association between a Person class and itself.  This is not a composition, because a child object needs to be able to exist independently of its parent object(s).  But is it an aggregate association?  The answer may depend on whether you are modelling families, or family trees, or forests of related family trees.  (Noting that even a family tree can be a DAG.)

There is already a good answer. But for the record, I'd like to make a blunter one.
The UML specification does not define any semantic for the shared aggregation anymore. This is not new. It's since UML 2.0, almost 20 years ago. Nevertheless, people continue to debate on what it is and what it is not. And teachers continue to teach it, because when they learned it, it was cool to debate on its use, , despite James Rumbaugh, one of the UML founder, called it already at that time a "modeling placebo" (i.e. if you use it or not, it doesn't really change anything)
In consequence, whenever you have the choice between aggregation and simple association, always prefer the simple association.
The composte aggregation, aka composition, is a very special relationship, where one class is responsible for the life and death of objects of another class. It is this one class and not a third one that is responsible for the composed instances.  Use it with extreme care, because this is a strong  constraint that is often not really needed.
In consequence, between  composition and simple association, prefer the simple association, unless you really need the  ownership semantics. Very often, a simple association with a 1 multiplicity may better represents what you want to model.
So in the end, it's the exact opposite of your assumption. The majority of associations should be simprl
associations, aggregations should be avoided and compositions be the exception.
And the simple associations can be very expressive when you use mutliplicity, dot notation, association name, role names and so on.

Yes, most of the replies in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/what-is-the-difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition are rubbish.
