# Code based examples on difference between Aggregation, Composition and Dependency

Tags: dependencies, aggregation, composition

What is the difference between different types of association i.e. aggregation, composition and dependency? explain with the help of code examples(in java, C++ or pseudo code).

Comment: Has anyone noticed that nobody does composition anymore? It's all aggregation and dependency injection anywhere you look.

Comment: Please, check the code-based example at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731802/what-is-the-difference-between-composition-and-association-relationship/23464244#23464244