# Difference between has-a and composed-of?

Tags: oop, data-modeling

In OOP modeling, is there any distinction between a "has-a" relationship and a "composed-of" relationship?

Comment: Is this repeat of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731802/what-is-the-difference-between-composition-and-association-relationship

Comment: Sunny, yes, thanks, looks like a repeat. I didn't see that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both statements usually mean *composition*.

But it seems to me that *composed-of* always means *composition* while *has-a* sometimes can mean *aggregation* (but not in the picture below). In UML it looks like:

[image]
<sub>(source: [atomicobject.com](http://www.atomicobject.com/images/UML_CompositionAggregation.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Not really, since both indicate that a parent object contains an instance of a child class. It's mostly a semantic difference where "has-a" represents an association between two different objects, where "composed-of" indicates that the child is an integral part of the parent.

Comment: An interesting question regarding the other answer is whether an engine can have an identity independent of the car in which it is mounted.

I would assert that the answer is yes.  I bought a replacement engine for a car once.  I would hope that the installers could distinguish the engine they removed from the one they installed.

Still, in many applications, an engine could be modeled as a subobject of car with no harm done.