# Association vs. Aggregation vs. Composition in Java

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to understand what these terms mean. And I came with few examples like:

Aggregation : Facebook **has a** user

Composition : Each user in facebook **has a** session.

Association : People **uses a** browser

But I'm getting confused with **has a** and **uses a** examples of mine. Why can't it be User **uses a** facebook account or Facebook **uses a** session to authenticate user?

Is that wrong in terms of OOP? Where I'm missing the concept?

Comment: [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/330447/Understanding-Association-Aggregation-and-Composit) is a nice article..that would help you understand..

Comment: and another [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731802/what-is-the-difference-between-composition-and-association-relationship?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what-is-the-difference-between-aggregation-composition-and-dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644273/what-is-the-difference-between-aggregation-composition-and-dependency)

Comment: Please see a code-based example at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731802/what-is-the-difference-between-composition-and-association-relationship/23464244#23464244

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **uses a** relationship means two things

->both can exist independently

->Data flows from the whole classifier(**people**) to the part classifier(**browser**)

The **has a** relationship means two things

->the lifetime of the part classifier(**session**) is dependent on the lifetime of the whole classifier(**facebook**)

->data usually flows in only one direction (that is, from the whole classifier(**facebook**) to the part classifier(**session**)).

Comment: Spot on.  Further, Association is the generic term; Aggregation (uses a) and Composition (has a) are types of Association.

Answer (score 2):

[This article from the Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/330447/Understanding-Association-Aggregation-and-Composit) makes a neat explanation of the Subject.

First of all there's no stone-written way to model a domain, there are several ways that are correct modeling approach to a particular problem. For example, your initial example uses a `Facebook` class and in your follow-up you're now using a `Facebook Account` type: using one or another (or maybe both) has impact un your model but doesn't invalidate it.

Saying that, according to the Code Project site an **association** relationship implies:

- Owner: No owner
- Life time: Have their own lifetime
- Child object: Child objects all are independent.

With that in mind, I don't think there's an association relationship between `User` and `Facebook Account` since they're highly dependant from each other (assuming User refers to a Facebook user), so a **composition** might be a better relationship.

I'm not sure what are you refering with your `Session` class. If it's [the period of time while the user is connecte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Login_session)d there is no sense in saying Facebook uses session for authentication and maybe the asociation relationship between `User` and `Session` can be an **agregation**, since a User can have several Sessions in a day an it's the owner of all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation) that precisely discusses aggregation VS composition

So, in Java terms, a Facebook User has a name (composition) and a Facebook User has a list of friends (Aggregation)

Comment: Your examples are fine, I changed them somewhat in hopes of making it more clear. I would only be careful with Association which, in UML terms, is correct, but put into Java, essentially means that a method from the other object is called. I'm homing in on Java because you added that tag to your question.